# Off-Grid Inverter causing a GFCI trip when charging EV

Tags: inverter, automotive, gfci

I have a transformer-less, 48VDC to 120/240VAC inverter that is off-grid. I have a 120VAC GFCI outlet wired to the inverter. When I plug my 120VAC EV charger into the outlet, the GFCI trips. It does **not** trip when I plug my laptop in. It does **not** when I wire the same GFCI outlet to the grid and charge my EV.

Why does this happen?

Could I add anything to prevent the GFCI trip? According to NEC it would need to be a class A 5mA trip GFCI.

Edit: It's a 12K Sol-Ark inverter. The battery is floating. No PV attached to simplify the problem. The inverter has a built-in ground bus bar. Neutral to ground bond is installed between the built-in neutral and ground bars.

Comment: Inverters have power switching circuits. All such circuits have high frequency harmonic voltage content that can generate harmonic currents to ground through noise suppression capacitors, and stray capacitance anywhere in the system including capacitance between the live wires and the ground wire in cables. That is likely the cause.

Comment: Interesting that the same device does not trip when attached to the grid though.  a $20 oscilloscope would let you compare the quality of sine waves you were getting, but inverters often achieve pseudo sine waves, like simulating a sine wave with square steps of different voltage, or simply PWMming the full voltage.  A less perfect sine wave could aggravate the harmonics Charles is mentioning and possibly cause the regulator to perform in an unexpected way if it's not designed to take that kind of input.

Comment: What make and model is your inverter?  Is your DC system floating, solidly grounded, or functionally grounded?  How is the AC side of the system grounded for that matter?

Comment: Oooh good point.  Pictures would help in case we can visually identify some flaw in the ground loop or installation, a block diagram of your batteries and charger system including the grounding concerns ThreePhaseEel is asking about may reveal a flaw as well.

Comment: For a high power device like an EV charger, the 5mA ground current required to trip the GFCI is not a large leakage.  A safety circuit could conceivably short something to ground, but I don't see why it would trip on the inverter and not a grid tie.

Comment: Most modern Electric Vehicle Supply Equipment (EVSE), or EV chargers, have built-in GFCI protection. When the unit is hardwired, there is no need for a GFCI breaker. If the unit is installed with a plug with a GFCI breaker, there can and will be faulty trips.

Comment: Your battery bank must be just silly big

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Edits added.

Comment: Check the wiring. May be ground mixed with neutral. And neutral grounding should be before receptacle. GFCI trips then currents on phase and neutral are not equal. Laptop may not consume the current to trip the device.

Comment: Which EV, and what charging cable are you using?

Comment: @Gil Agreed. However, this is an outdoor outlet which according to NEC must be GFCI protected.

Comment: Many comply with the NEC with the built in GFCI and have the UL label. Since I have no idea of what model he is using I based my answer on the ones I am familiar with which are directly wired to the mains. This appears to work, but not with a line cord. Also cascading GFCI units can cause false trips.